# Как исправить странное поведение некоторых элементов при зуме страницы?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Получил страницу на которой надо пофиксить баги и никак не могу понять, почему при зуме, например некоторые span из которых состоит иконка бургер меню, меняют свой визуальный размер по сравнению со своими соседями, то крайние жирнее выглядят, то первые два, при том, что максимальная высота жестко задана

Вот страница: https://109k4.github.io/hogoGitHub/

Comment: Это погрешности рендеринга. Если хотите, чтобы иконка выглядела "smooth", сделайте её в svg.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуй вместо свойства height и background-color для элемента span использовать border-bottom.
Например, так

```
border-bottom: 2px solid #223F83;
```

Comment: Работает только для мозилы, в хроме проблема не исчезает

Answer (score -1):

В файле index.css в 2549 убери height: 25px. По идее должно отображаться нормально

Так как иконка прописана svg кодом через background-image это может как то и влияет на результат.

Как вариант переделай бургер меню